# whats the difference between @input and v-model?

Tags: forms, vue.js

I have the same:

```
  <step-input
            @input="_updatePersonTaxDocument"
            v-model="account_raw.person_tax_document">
  </step-input>
```

Whats the difference between @input and v-model?

Comment: ^ specifically [this section](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components)

Comment: I think @input and v-model are different when updating data. look at this [link](https://www.programmersought.com/article/95481251977/) and you know what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

`@input="handler"` is a shorthand syntax for `v-on:input="handler"` which is a way to bind an [event handler](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) - whenever component (or native HTML element) raises an `input` event, the `handler` will be called...

`v-model` has different meaning on [native input element](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage) and on [custom components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#v-model-with-Components) but its always a shorthand for `:value="xxx" @ev="xxx = $event"` (with `v-model="xxx"`)

You should really try and read some docs before asking such questions...